# Getting error 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)' when Posting video on facebook from iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting an error(The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.))when posting video from ios device. I have used these code for posting video on facebook.

```
-(void)FBUploadVideoProcess
{
    NSString *finalFileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/Book_%d/%@_%d.mov",self.book.bookId,self.book.bookName,self.book.bookId];
    NSString *filePathOfVideo = [NSHomeDirectory()
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:finalFileName];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathOfVideo];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"animation1.mp4",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               self.book.bookName, @"name",
                               @"FlipIt Movie", @"description",
                               nil];

   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
   {
       [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if(!error)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                  UIAlertView *alrtResult=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlipIt" message:@"Upload Complete." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                  [alrtResult show];

                                  [spinner stopAnimating];

                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  UIAlertView *alrtResult=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlipIt" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                  [alrtResult show];
                                  [spinner stopAnimating];

                              }
                          }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
    // OPEN Session!
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone  allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         if (error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Login fail :%@",error);
                                             UIAlertView *alrtResult=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlipIt" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                             [alrtResult show];
                                             [spinner stopAnimating];
                                         }
                                         else //if(FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"session...%d",FBSession.activeSession.isOpen);
                                             [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                          parameters:params
                                                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                                       if(!error)
                                                                       {

                                                                           NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                                                           UIAlertView *alrtResult=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlipIt" message:@"Upload Complete." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                                                           [alrtResult show];

                                                                           [spinner stopAnimating];
                                                                       }
                                                                       else
                                                                       {


                                                                           NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                           UIAlertView *alrtResult=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlipIt" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                                                           [alrtResult show];
                                                                           [spinner stopAnimating];
                                                                       }

                                                                   }];
                                         }
                                     }];
     }

}
```

I have found lot of question related it, but yet I have not found my solution. Please help me.

Comment: can u show your error message plz..

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Comment: friend I need the full error messge

Comment: @Anbu,Thanks for comments. But I'm unable to post full error message,because it is too long.

Comment: friend **com.facebook.sdk error 5.** given the multi type of errors result.just wait

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.),,I'm getting this error only first time when I'm attempt to share video and from second time video is posting successfully,but from next time facebook login window is not coming even I'm logging out from browser as well as facebook app. Please help me.

Comment: and error statement is:: the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.

Answer (score 0):

You should match destination format to source video format which is mov. Also "name" should be changed to "title".

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           videoData, @"animation1.mov",
                           @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                           self.book.bookName, @"title",
                           @"FlipIt Movie", @"description",
                           nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But still I'm getting the error.

Comment: @Monikanta Did you change mp4 to mov?

Comment: @Monikanta Also confirm the video format is "mov" format exactly.

Comment: ,Yes Video format is in 'mov' and I'm getting the error only for first time and from next time it is working fine.

Comment: @Monikanta You need to check code related with FB access tokens.